# DML Exception Insert failed.

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test

This is somewhat of a re-post, but I have additional questions.

Some quick background of what I'm trying to do..

The following is my Apex Trigger. It is a validation Trigger on Sampling_c which will validate that Country_c is a Valid country using Validation_country_c. When it validates Country_c it will look into State_province_c and will then validate that it is actually a state So .. If Country_c = US and State_province_c = CA then we are okay. But IF Country_c = US and State_province_c = ZZ221(whatever) it should fail. Now these condition checks only triggers when Override_c = 'Yes'.

Below is the test class, which is working and I get 100% but I believe it is "artificial"  The reason that I say that is because I am populating Validation_Region__c with information through my test class.  But in my program It should be done by my For Loop, so my question is there something wrong with my For Loop? Or is this an expected outcome.  This is my first Apex trigger and I'm still trying to understand Test Classes.

As I said above this test class works 100% but If I remove

```
  Validation_Region__c region = new Validation_Region__c();
   region.Country_Key__c = 'US';
   region.Description__c = 'California';  
  insert region;
```

It Breaks, and gives me an error System.DmlException:Insert failed. First Exception on row 0; first error : cannot_Insert_update_activate_entity, OverrideTrigger: Execution of Before Insert

```
@IsTest
public class OverrideTest{

static testmethod void addressOverride(){

    Sampling__c s = new Sampling__c();

   Validation_Region__c region = new Validation_Region__c();
   region.Country_Key__c = 'US';
   region.Description__c = 'California';  
  insert region;

s.Quantity_of_Samples__c = 2;
s.Override__c = 'Yes';
s.Country__c = 'US';
s.State_Province__c = 'California';
//s.Override_Default_Ship_Method__c = True;

try 
{
insert S;  
}
 catch
 (DmlException e) 
 {
system.assert(false,e.getMessage()+' '+ e.getLineNumber());
}

}
}
```

The Error that I am getting is System.DmlException:Insert failed. First Exception on row 0; first error : cannot_Insert_update_activate_entity, OverrideTrigger: Execution of Before Insert

Can anyone give me some guidance?

```
trigger OverrideTrigger on Sampling__c (before insert,before update) {

// Top level map is keyed by Country. Inner Map is keyed by Region   
Map<String, Map<String, Validation_Region__c>> validRegions = new Map<String,        Map<String, Validation_Region__c>>();
// ...

For(Validation_Region__c objR : [Select Id,Country_Key__c,Description__c,Name FROM    Validation_Region__c]){

String countryKey = objR.Country_Key__c;

Map<String, Validation_Region__c> regionMap = validRegions.get(countryKey);
// Maybe rework to use Map.containsKey rather than null check. Would be cleaner.

if(regionMap == null) {
regionMap = new Map<String, Validation_Region__c>();
validRegions.put(countryKey, regionMap);
}
string regionKey = objR.Description__c; 
regionMap.put( regionKey,objR);
}


for( Sampling__c s : Trigger.new){
 If((s.Country__c != null) && (S.Override__c == 'Yes')){
 String countryKey = s.Country__c;
 String regionKey = s.State_Province__c;

    System.debug('This is the countryKey'+validRegions.get(countryKey));
    System.debug('This is the regionKey'   +validRegions.get(countryKey).get(regionKey));

        if(validRegions.get(countryKey) != null &&   validRegions.get(countryKey).get(regionKey) != null) {
            // The Region belongs to the country
            System.debug('This is the validRegions'+validRegions );
            Validation_Region__c vr= validRegions.get(countryKey).get(regionKey);
            System.debug('22345 This is VR'+vr);
        }else{
                System.debug('Breaking');
             break;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct me if I am wrong, but you believe that since you already have some fields in the database you shouldn't need to be inserting the Validation_Region__c in your test class.  Inserting this makes you believe you are specifically setting the value.

From reading your question, it comes off as the above is what you believe in shorter terms.  If this is the case, then the real issue is that you don't understand how test classes work.  When you run a test class, it is as if the database is completely empty.  So when you are looking for values in code that is being executed from the test, it won't find them unless the test itself adds them in there.  So, when you are inserting the Validation_Region__c record in your test class it is not setting that value from the test class.  It is simply enabling it found by the query and then assigned by your loop.

So the test class is doing exactly what you intended for it to do.  Your confusion was around the inserting of what could be called 'pre-test' data that needs to exist in order for your trigger to execute correctly.  Let me know if this isn't clear.

Comment: "When you run a test class, it is as if the database is completely empty." This is what I was looking for I believe, So validRegions won't be full of my Validation_Region__c object?  I expected validRegions to get populated when I ran the trigger, instead what I'm doing in my test class is adding US and California which is why I called it "artificial."  So What I believe I am unclear on the the 'pre-test'.  My confusin comes in that I am "hard coding" values into my test class, but yet I have a for loop that should do it for me. Is my trigger right? Will this work properly if I deploy it ndev?

Comment: Yes.  You just need to make sure you keep the line you were wondering about in the test.  All tests should contain lines like this.  Basically, before your actual test you set up data like this.  Think of when you run a test, starting on a clean empty database.